# OnLongPress does not work properly on tablets android

Tags: android, tablet, android-gesture

Hi I am developing an app in which on long press I will be able to move the icon and on single tap I perform some activities.

The app works fine in mobile phones but does not work completely in tablets.

In tablet it does not detect onLongPess just the single tap.

I actually need to press very lightly on the icon for the tablet to detect onLongPess if I try it roughly as I would in my mobile phone it does not detect at all.
Why is it?. Do we need to handle differently for tablets?

Can anyone please help me? I am pretty sure my code is fine since it runs perfectly in all mobile phones.

Comment: Could you maybe show us some relevant code? How are we supposed to help you just from that description? And also which specific tablet are you talking about?

Comment: @XaverKapeller on nexus 7 tablet.. okay will update the my question with some code

Comment: @XaverKapeller i have roughly taken the code and have put it. Hope you understand it

Comment: hehehe  :P !!!! go to sleep dude

Comment: @Pankaj idiot. I cant money is on line :P

Comment: @Pankaj solve if u can

Comment: its solved thanks for your time both of you appreciate it :)